# DELETE records Except Max Category ID per User - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have following Table, [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/343f1a/6)

For every user, I want to delete all records Except the Maximum Category ID.

So My Table should look like as you can see the 2nd query result in SQLFiddle

I tried following but no use.

```
DELETE FROM tbl_categories
    WHERE category_id NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MAX(n.category_id)
                            FROM tbl_categories n
                        GROUP BY n.user_id) x)
```

Comment: Then what is the problem in your query?

Comment: `DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL`

I guess it does not allow SELECT staement in FROM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also write it like this:

```
delete
t1.*
from
tbl_categories t1
left join tbl_categories t2 on t1.category_id < t2.category_id 
                            and t1.user_id = t2.user_id
where t2.category_id is not null;
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/879a1/1/0)

Comment: So which one is good performance wise .... ? I will accept that answer :P

Yours or @Aziz

Comment: We can't answer that, it depends on your data. You have to try or you can inspect the query plan. Execute `EXPLAIN <your_query_here>;` and you will see, if it can use indexes, if it does and so on. This can get you an idea of which one is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You query is almost correct but you have not used `user_id` in your WHERE clause, like this:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_categories
WHERE (user_id, category_id) NOT IN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT t1.user_id, MAX(t1.category_id) as category_id
    FROM tbl_categories t1
    GROUP BY t1.user_id
  ) t
)
```

Working fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22a7d/1